# having issues in configuring java JAVA_HOME and maven M2_HOME on amazon linux ec2 instance

Tags: java, maven, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I just unzipped **jdk1.8.0_251.tar.gz** and **apache-maven-3.6.3.tar.gz** into **/opt** directory as root.
,
Then I add the following into ~/.bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_251/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME
```

I verified `java -version` command and its working fine. But when I checked `mvn --version` command, its saying that JAVA_HOME should point to JDK not JRE.

so,

I again edited ~/.bash_profile as below

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_251
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME

export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME
```

Now, **`mvn --version`** is working fine but `**java --version**` is not working.

What should I do now???

Comment: check maven command `mvn -v` in new command prompt.

Comment: The definition of `JAVA_HOME` is wrong cause it has to be `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_251`. Furthermore you only need the entry `/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin` in your PATH anything else is not needed nor necessary and can be omitted.